# Hiding an element while JS runs in the background then show again

Tags: javascript, function

Basically, this is what I wish to do:

> 1. Hide element1
> 2. Run JS function relating to element1
> 3. Show element1

The purpose is to not show the element to the user while it is being modified by the JS in the background and once the JS function has been executed, show that element again. This way the user doesn't see all the changes happening.

So, is it possible to change the CSS of an element based on a JS function completing it's execution?

**Context:**

I'm running a test on our website between the control and an experiment. The website loads up the page, then fires my test code (the JS I'm talking about above). Therefore, the user sees the normal website, then it disappears and they see the changes happening before it finally loads up the test. This is awful from a UX perspective so my plan is keep everything appearing as white space until the final version has loaded up - hence the question.

Comment: *"So, is it possible to change the CSS of an element based on a JS function completing it's execution"*. Of course. What part exactly is a problem ?

Comment: You seem to misunderstand something: if your function is synchronous, you don't have to hide the element: no rendering is done until your code finishes. Please clarify your goal. As it is your function is too vague to get a real answer.

Comment: typically an execution of a function takes a few ms so the changes are happening instantly from the point of view of an user. What does your function do? How long it takes to complete?

Comment: @marzelin even if it takes 1 second no rendering will happen.

Comment: @DenysSéguret but the browser will be frozen for 1s

Comment: From the edit it looks like it's not a "function" but an asynchronous operation. Just hide the element, do the thing, then show it again. **What part is a problem ?**

Comment: Added some context - the JS changes are visible for approx. 3 seconds. It's just changing some styling and arrangement of text for an entire page.

Comment: Looks like FOUC problem. One way is to add loading screen that covers the whole page when the function starts and remove it when the function finishes.

Comment: another way is to make the changes happen lazily, that is halt them till all the code is run and then flush the all the changes in one cycle.

Comment: the simplest way is make test code block rendering or detach `body` from the document and put it back when all the changes are completed.This way what the user initially sees is white space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('#container').hide();
var content='';
for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
{
content+='<tr><td> Row No'+(i+1)+'</td><td> User'+(i+1)+'</td></tr>';
}
$('#tbl').append(content);
$('#tbl tr:gt(5)').remove();

$('#btnShow').click(function(){
$('#container').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'>
<table id='tbl'>
<tr><td> Row Number</td> <td> User Name</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Show UI" id="btnShow"/>
```

Code is self explaining. Wrap your to things under a parent div, hide it before all rendering, then show the parent div again when you ready to go!!!